# Increment React state when Typescript is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to increment value of React state `setMoviesPage` by 1 each time `handleScroll()` is called.
However, I get Typescript error `Parameter 'prev' implicitly has an 'any' type`.

This is my code:

```
  const [moviesPage, setMoviesPage] = useState(1);


  async function handleScroll() {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
    await setIsFetching(true);
    setMoviesPage(prev => prev + 1);
  }
```

How should solve it? Thanks

Comment: Would you try to explicitly set `prev` type: `setMoviesPage((prev: number) => prev + 1)`? Or you can strong type this state variable from the very beginning, something like `const [moviesPage, setMoviesPage] = useState<number|null>(null)`

Comment: Could you show us how `useState` is called in your code?

Comment: Change your state to: `setMoviesPage({...state, [movieStateName] : [movieStateName] + 1});`. Here `movieStateName` is the name of your state which you would like to change it and you've not mentioned it in your question.

Comment: And, by the way, trigger data fetching with scroll handler doesn't look like a good idea. I would rather load necessary data proactively and implemented [intersection observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov changing the state to `useState<number|null>(null)` does not help. In case I also call the setter as `setMoviesPage((prev: number) => prev + 1)`, I get an error `Argument of type '(prev: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.` Also, many thanks for mentioning Intersection Observer API, I'll read about it

Comment: @Aitwar, yes, done

Comment: Considering you initiate `moviesPage` with number (`1`), you may try `const [moviesPage, setMoviesPage] = useState<number>(1)`. With that, you may simplify that problematic call doing simply `setMoviesPage(moviesPage + 1)`.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov the most  solutions are the simple ones. many thanks for sharing your knowledge